# Does ehcache keeps all the keys in physical memory?

Tags: caching, memory-management, ehcache

When Ehcache is configured in overflowToDisk mode, do all the keys reside in memory and all the values are pushed into disk? If the keys are also serialised to disk, how will ehcache maneger will do lookup?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like community version of disk store keeps all the keys in memory. Enterprise version of EhCache disk store claims to address this problem using Bigmemory. Please refer http://forums.terracotta.org/forums/posts/list/5032.page